# Input/output shapes of GANs for sequential data

Tags: python, time-series, mxnet, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to do time series prediction using GANs. I am using MXNet/Gluon. Thus, I have a sequential data of size (N, 1), which I have transformed it into (N-stepsize, stepsize). Now I have a hard time understanding the input out shapes of the network. Here, the code for Generator and Discriminator networks.

```
netG = nn.Sequential()
with netG.name_scope():
    netG.add(nn.Dense(20))
    netG.add(nn.BatchNorm(momentum = 0.8))
    netG.add(nn.Dropout(0.5))
    netG.add(nn.Dense(15))
    netG.add(nn.BatchNorm(momentum = 0.8))
    netG.add(nn.Dropout(0.5))
    netG.add(nn.Dense(20))
    netG.add(nn.BatchNorm(momentum = 0.8))
    netG.add(nn.Dropout(0.5))
    netG.add(nn.Dense(step_size, activation = "tanh"))


#300, 50, 2
#input shape is inferred
netD = nn.Sequential()
with netD.name_scope():
    netD.add(nn.Dense(20))
    netG.add(nn.BatchNorm(momentum = 0.8))
    netD.add(nn.Dense(15, activation='tanh'))
    netG.add(nn.BatchNorm(momentum = 0.8))
    netD.add(nn.Dense(20, activation='tanh'))
    netD.add(nn.Dense(step_size))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the tensor shapes with the following code:
`print(mx.viz.print_summary(netG(mx.sym.var('data')), shape={'data':(1,100,10)}))`
I am assuming here that N-stepsize is equal 100 and stepsize is equal 10.

You have 2 errors in the discriminator: you add the Batchnorm layers to `netG` instead of `netD`